# CRTP versus direct implementation of the function in the "derived"

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I am trying to get a better understanding of CRTP. So far my understanding is that it allows one to write a functions like the following.

```
template <class T>
void foo(Base<T> x ) { x.do_stuff() }
```

Now, depending on the actual compile time derived object `x` that is passed to the function `foo()`, it will do different things.

However, I could have derived the class `Derived` from `Base` and masked/shadowed its `do_stuff()` with a non-virtual but overridden `Derived::do_stuff`. So when exactly is it correct to use CRTP, rather the simplest non-trivial example which shows the advantage of CRTP over shadowing/masking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of the CRTP is to be able to get the derived object's type without virtuality. If you do

```
struct B { void foo() const; }
struct D : B { void foo() const; }

void bar(const B& x) { x.foo(); }
```

then `bar` calls `B::foo` and not `D::foo` when you pass a `D` object, since `foo` isn't a virtual function. If you want `D::foo` to be called, then you *need* either virtual functions, or CRTP.

With the simplest kind of CRTP:

```
template <typename>
struct B { void foo() const; }

struct D : B<D> { void foo() const; }

template <typename T>
void bar(const B<T>& x)
{
    static_cast<const T&>(x).foo();
}
```

this calls `D::foo()` when you pass to `bar` a `D` object.

An alternative CRTP trick, which however forces `D` to provide an implementation for `foo`, is

```
template <typename T>
struct B
{
    void foo() const { static_cast<const T*>(this)->foo_impl(); }
    // default implementation if needed
    // void foo_impl() const { ... }
};

struct D : B<D> { void foo_impl() const { ... } };

template <typename T>
void bar(const B<T>& x) { x.foo(); }
```

but you still need a template parameter for `B` (so that `foo` dispatches correctly), and therefore a template `bar` function.

Also, if you don't do CRTP, you'd better have a virtual destructor, which might add unwanted overhead for lightweight classes which are meant to be completely inlined. With CRTP you will simply write a protected destructor (private destructor + `friend T` in C++0x).

Comment: > then bar calls B::foo and not D::foo ...oh of course! what was I thinking.